# Submit form on Image pixel load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, submit, pixel

I have a form that needs to load an image pixel on submit. The problem I am noticing, is that the form is being submitted before the image can load. I would like to wait for the image to load before submitting the form. I also need to keep this modular, so that it can be used for multiple images and multiple forms on the same page.

```
function loadImgPixel(pixelSrc){
    //the image pixel simply needs to load, not be displayed so there is no need to append this to the body element
    $("<img />").attr("src",pixelSrc).on("load",function(){
       return true;
    })
}

$("#myform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    form = $(this);
    var pix1 = loadPixel("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sports-balls/1024/BasketBall.png");
    var pix2 = loadPixel("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sports-balls/128/Tennis_ball.png");
    if(pix1 && pix2){
       form.unbind("submit")  //unbind submit so there isn't an endless loop due to 'preventDefault'
       .submit();             //submit form;
    }

})
```

When I do an `alert` on my `loadImgPixel(pixelSrc)` function. It throws back `undefined`. It seems like it is attempting to see the return value before `.on("load")` can actually `return true`.

Issue#2: the `.unbind` section of the code snippet was used to prevent a loop that may be caused like the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605522/how-to-wait-until-image-is-loaded-in-jquery). However when I unbind and submit right after, nothing happens.

BONUS POINTS: Lets say i needed to load 30 pixels on a form submit, what would be the most efficient method to make sure all are loaded before submitting the form. I would like to think there is a better way to check than just if`(pix1 && pix2 && pix3 $$ pix4....){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `.load` event of the `image-element` is asynchronous in nature. You can not be certain when `src` of the element will be loaded.

To handle such `asynchronous` activities, we can use `callback` or `Promise`

> The [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object is used for deferred and asynchronous computations. A Promise represents an operation that hasn't completed yet, but is expected in the future.

To determine all the promises are *done*, either `fulfilled` or `rejected`, we use [`Promise.all(iterable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method.

The result of `resolve` is passed as an array of values from all the promises. To test whether all the `resolved` values pass certain test, we can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
function loadPixel(pixelSrc) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $("<img />").attr("src", pixelSrc).on("load", function() {
      resolve(true);
    }).on('error', function() {
      reject();
    });
  });
}

$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  var pix1 = loadPixel("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sports-balls/1024/BasketBall.png");
  var pix2 = loadPixel("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sports-balls/128/Tennis_ball.png");
  Promise.all([pix1, pix2]).then(function(values) {
    var res = values.every(Boolean);
    if (res) {
      form.unbind("submit").submit();
    }
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id='myform'>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/s6d0br4z/)

Comment: Haven't tried implementing this yet, but seems like it does the trick. Will let you know how it goes.Thanks! Never knew about this method. I will do some googling to learn some more. Let me know if you have anything to recommend

Comment: How would this look in jquery vs javascript? Is there an equivalent of the promise.all function in jquery? All i've been able to find is `.when` which allows you to pass multiple values.

Comment: Yes!.. `$.when` is `jQuery` solution!